# Create TextBox Component c#

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to create a custom class which inherits a text box control in c# but I dont know where to start. Ive done some research an i believe this class should be a drag able visual component (dll file).

Okay so based on responses here is what ive done so far;

```
class PTextBox : TextBox
{

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }     

    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```

}

**I want to get the users input, allow the first 11 numbers to be entered in black and anything more then that, text color will change to red**

Comment: Do you have any code? Did you try anything?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: code is now added

Answer (score 1):

WinForms?  If so, just add a class that Inherits from TextBox:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{

}
```

Then re-build the application and you should get a new control at the top of your toolbox:

[image]

Obviously, you'll need to add code to make your inherited TextBox meet your needs...

Comment: cheers! I want to get the users input, allow the first 11 numbers to be entered in black and anything more then that, text color will change to red . How can i do this?

Comment: In that case, inherit from a **RichTextBox** instead. This will allow you to color the text as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Searching this key words : WinAPI + textbox, WinAPI Inspector